# Compute $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(-1\right)^k\binom{2n-k}k$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

$$S_n=\sum _{k=0}^n\left(-1\right)^k\binom{2n-k}k=\begin{cases} 
      1 & n\equiv0\pmod3 \\
      0 & n\equiv1\pmod3\\
      -1 &  n\equiv-1\pmod3
   \end{cases}
$$

I can show that $S_1 = 0$, $S_2 = -1$, and $S_3 = 1$. But how to show it for $S_n$?

Comment: Most likely an induction problem.

Comment: yeah, but how to show for Sn?

Comment: Can you show that if $S_n=0$, then $S_{n+1}=-1,\ S_{n+2}=1,$ and $S_{n+3}=0$?  Then show that $S_1=0$ and you are done.

Comment: Use `\binom{n}{k}` to get the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way, perhaps, is to prove a bit more. Define

$$s_n=\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n-k}k\;,$$

so that $S_n=s_{2n}$. (Note that there is no need to specify limits on $k$: only finitely many terms are non-zero, since $\binom{n}k=0$ if $k>n$ or $k<0$, and those are the ones that we want.) Then

$$\begin{align*}
s_{n+1}&=\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n+1-k}k\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^k\left(\binom{n-k}k+\binom{n-k}{k-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n-k}k+\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-1-k}k\\
&=s_n-\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n-1-k}k\\
&=s_n-s_{n-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now $s_0=1=s_1$, and an easy induction establishes the result that

$$s_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod6\\
1,&\text{if }n\equiv1\pmod6\\
0,&\text{if }n\equiv2\pmod6\\
-1,&\text{if }n\equiv3\pmod6\\
-1,&\text{if }n\equiv4\pmod6\\
0,&\text{if }n\equiv5\pmod6\;,
\end{cases}$$

from which the desired result for $S_n$ follows at once.

Comment: (+1). This is the more intuitive answer. Maybe I can interest the reader in the Egorychev method with what I have posted below.

Comment: beautiful solution (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$Q_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {2n-k\choose k} =
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {2n-k\choose 2n-2k}.$$

Introduce

$${2n-k\choose 2n-2k} = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n-2k+1}} (1+z)^{2n-k} \; dz.$$

Observe that this vanishes for $k\gt  n$ so we may extend the range of
$k$ in the sum to infinity, getting

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k}}{(1+z)^{k}}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{1+z^2/(1+z)}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} (1+z)^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{1+z+z^2}
\; dz.$$

Now put  $w =  z/(1+z)$ so  that $z=w/(1-w)$ and  $dz =  1/(1-w)^2 dw$
which takes $z=0$ to $w=0$ to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}}
\frac{1}{1+w/(1-w)+w^2/(1-w)^2}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-2w+w^2+w(1-w)+w^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-w+w^2}
\; dw.$$

Solving $1-w+w^2=0$ we obtain the two roots

$$\rho_{0,1} = -\exp(\pm 2\pi i/3)$$

which yield

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}}
\frac{1}{(w-\rho_0)(w-\rho_1)}
\; dw.$$

The  residues sum  to  zero so  we get  from  the four  poles at  $0$,
$\rho_0$, $\rho_1$ and infinity

$$Q_n + \frac{1}{\rho_0-\rho_1} \rho_0^{-2n-1}
+ \frac{1}{\rho_1-\rho_0} \rho_1^{-2n-1}
+ \mathrm{Res}_{w=\infty} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-w+w^2} = 0.$$

The last term is

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2}
w^{2n+1} \frac{1}{1-1/w+1/w^2}
= -\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
w^{2n+1} \frac{1}{w^2-w+1}
= 0.$$

We thus obtain the closed form

$$Q_n + \frac{1}{\rho_0-\rho_1} \rho_0^{-2n-1}
- \frac{1}{\rho_0-\rho_1} \rho_1^{-2n-1} = 0$$

or $$Q_n = \frac{1}{\rho_0-\rho_1} 
(\rho_1^{-2n-1} - \rho_0^{-2n-1})
\\ = \frac{1}{\rho_1-\rho_0} 
(\exp(-2\pi i(-2n-1)/3)-\exp(2\pi i(-2n-1)/3))
\\ = \frac{2i}{\rho_1-\rho_0} 
\sin(-2\pi(-2n-1)/3)
\\ = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}
\sin(2\pi(2n+1)/3).$$

Now observe that

$$Q_{n+3} = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}
\sin(2\pi(2n+1)/3+4\pi) = Q_n$$

hence the sequence is periodic with period three.
Furthermore

$$Q_0 = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}\sin(2\pi/3) = 1,\;
Q_1 = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3} \sin(2\pi) = 0, 
\\ \text{and}\quad
Q_2 = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}\sin(10\pi/3) = -1.$$

Therefore the sequence $Q_n$ is

$$1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, \ldots$$

as claimed.

Comment: Oh wow, I most certainly did not expect contour integrals in a problem like this!

Comment: Try \oint for closed integrals.